# How to add a delay in angular component?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have an angular component inside a modal dialog. When the dialog is closed, I want to delay closing of the modal dialog.

How can I add delay for 5 seconds inside an Angular component before closing it?

Answer (score 2):

You can have an event handler like "onClose" in whatever dialog you are using and add delay in that, then close the modal.

[Angular Material Dialog](https://stackblitz.com/angular/aynkqmkjgol?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts)

```
 onNoClick(): void {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.dialogRef.close();
    },5000); 

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> One way you can delay your dialog is, by using timeOut, And you can also pass some information back to your modal dialog.

```
    onCloseClickHandler(e: any): void {
       setTimeout(() => {
      this.dialogRef.close(e);
    }, 5000);
  }
```